# On Time and countdown (seconds) event handler for radio button

Tags: java, ontime

I must create an application which basically has to open a blinking window, at a future moment set by the user or in the second case, with a delay of 1-5 seconds, decided by the user. Below is the code I tried to write, but I'm stuck on creating the event handler and the actions. And how to parse the input from the user in the write format of time. And also I am not sure if I should have used the threads.

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.util.Hashtable;
import javax.swing.*;

import static javax.swing.JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE;




public class MyTimer {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Object[] options = {"Settings",
                "Close"};
        JFrame f = new JFrame();

        f.setLayout(new GridLayout(6, 3));
        f.setSize(500, 800);

        f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        Hashtable<String, String> values = new Hashtable<>();
        values.put("  :  :  ","On time :");
        values.put("  ","Countdown (seconds)");


        ButtonsAdd.addPair(values, f);

        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        JButton ChooseColor= new JButton("Choose Color");
        JLabel lbl1= new JLabel("No color  was selected");
        lbl1.setSize(150, 150);
        f.add(lbl1);
        f.add(ChooseColor);
        JLabel lbl2= new JLabel("Speed");
        f.add(lbl2);
        Choice speed = new Choice();
        speed.setSize(150, 150);
        speed.setBackground(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
        speed.add("1");
        speed.add("2");
        speed.add("3");
        speed.add("4");
        speed.add("5");
        String n ;

        if (speed.getSelectedItem().equals("1")) {
            n = String.valueOf("1");
        }

        if (speed.getSelectedItem().equals("2")) {
            n = String.valueOf("2");
        }
        if (speed.getSelectedItem().equals("3")) {
            n = String.valueOf("3");
        }

        if (speed.getSelectedItem().equals("4")) {
            n = String.valueOf("4");
        }
        if (speed.getSelectedItem().equals("5")) {
            n = String.valueOf("5");
        }
        f.add(speed);
        ButtonGroup sTsT = new ButtonGroup();
        JRadioButton Start = new JRadioButton("Start");
        JRadioButton Stop  = new JRadioButton("Stop");
        Start.setSelected(true);
        Stop.setSelected(false);
        sTsT.add(Start);
        sTsT.add(Stop);


        f.add(Start);
        f.add(Stop);
        JColorChooser jcc= new JColorChooser();
        ChooseColor.setActionCommand("hello");

        JDialog dialog = JColorChooser.createDialog(null, "Choose color", true,jcc, new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                Color c = jcc.getColor();
                lbl1.setForeground(c);
                lbl1.setText("The color you chose");
            }
        }, null);

        Start.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

                JFrame b = new JFrame();
                b.setVisible(true);
              b.setBackground(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
                b.setSize(500, 800);


            }

        });
        ActionListener myAl = new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                if(e.getActionCommand().equals("hello"))
                    dialog.setVisible(true);


            }
        };
        ChooseColor.addActionListener(myAl);




        int answer = JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(null, "Choose option", "Option dialog", JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION, JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE,null, options, options[0]);


        if (answer == 0){


            f.setVisible(true);
            f.setBackground(Color.ORANGE);}
    }}
```

```
import java.util.Enumeration;
import java.util.Hashtable;
import javax.swing.*;


public class ButtonsAdd {public static void addPair(Hashtable<String,String> values, JFrame f) {
    Enumeration e = values.keys();
    while(e.hasMoreElements()) {
        Object key = e.nextElement();
        JTextField tf = new JTextField(key.toString());
        ButtonGroup myChoices = new ButtonGroup();
        JRadioButton OnTime = new JRadioButton(values.get(key));
        JRadioButton Countdown  = new JRadioButton(values.get(key));
        OnTime.setSelected(true);

        myChoices.add(OnTime);
        myChoices.add(Countdown);
        f.getContentPane().add(OnTime);
        f.getContentPane().add(tf);

    }
}
}
```